# Installing VMD with python support on MAC

Tags: python, macos, installation, vmd

I have been trying to install VMD1.9.2 on a Macbook with python support but have not been able to. It seems to me that the packaged .dmg file for VMD comes without Python support. I have used the command `vmdinfo options` to find the options my VMD is installed with and `MACOSXX86 FLTKOPENGL FLTK TK ACTC CUDA IMD LIBSBALL LIBTACHYON VRPN NETCDF TCL PTHREADS SILENT` this is the result which shows that it does not have Python support. My question- Is there an easy way to add python support rather than compiling from source? I just drag the App after unpacking the .dmg file to Applications folder. Am I doing something wrong while installing it this way? Is there any other way at all?

`

Comment: As far as I know, you have to compile from source, no way around it.

Comment: As I understand, VMD is using TCL, not python.  http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/pythonlib/  Quite old version has the Python and not for the MACos.

Answer (score 0):

Robin Betz has created the [`vmd-python`](https://github.com/Eigenstate/vmd-python) package. You can install it with `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge vmd-python
```

More informations can be found in the [package documentation](https://vmd.robinbetz.com/).